# Directory-specific issues for htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a site, which has the following folders

testing1
and its subfolders:

myfolder

myfolder2

myfolder3

This is the .htaccess file for it:

```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
   php_value auto_append_file testing1.php
```

This works for the main directory, but how can I make changes from a single .htaccess file without having to place one in every directory (I use cPanel and copy-and-paste them across for now).

The directory myfolder2 contains a multi-page flipbook (converted from PDF) created in AXMAG, a flipbook software (can't post links yet - but look it up on Google). I want to leave the files intact, but at the sametime append the site notice to them which is:

```
© My company here 2012. Content copyrighted
```

How can I do per-directory .htaccess for autoappend, and add-type html .htm.

BTW, myfolder2 went blank on the HTML page when I put the .htaccess in - what am I doing wrong? No issues for the other directories though.

I would appreciate any help with this, although I can do htaccess there's some bits of it I'm still new to.

Comment: Nice question. But I would utilize a scripting language like PHP to get this task done.

Comment: The contents are all PHP, **except** myfolder2 which is HTML/Flash (a flipbook). How could I do this in PHP for my subfolders then?

Comment: I mean you should concatenate using PHP includes, rather than `auto_append_file`

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess normally works by cascading down directories.  The most maintainable way if you want to fully leverage them would likely be to create an application wide .htaccess file in the top level of your directory and then group everything else in subfolders according to the .htaccess functionality you're looking for.  For instance having something like:

```
app/
  .htaccess <-- App wide settings
  php/
    .htaccess <-- PHP section settings which modify app-wide
    scripts/ <-- Some PHP settings here
  html/
    .htaccess <-- HTML section settings which modify app-wide
    pages/ 
    embeds/
```